# Django not cascading on delete

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm realizing more and more that I'm still a Django noob, I can't seem to figure out what's happening with my data model and why it's not cascading deletes. Here is my model.

```
class message(models.Model):
     msg_text = models.CharField(max_length = 9900)
     date_time = models.DateTimeField()
     is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)


 class thread(models.Model):
     message = models.ForeignKey(message)
     subject = models.CharField(max_length=160)
     from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'from_user')
     to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'to_user')
     thread_id = models.CharField(max_length = 36)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.subject
```

And then here is my delete function

```
def delete_message(request, thread_id):
     t = thread.objects.get(id=thread_id)
     thread.objects.filter(thread_id = t.thread_id).delete()

     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("inbox.views.index"))
```

So every thread has messages attached to it, and all the threads that contain related messages (ie replies) are all related with a thread id which is a randomly generated string. 
So when I delete I get the initial thread id (django auto-generated id) and then use it to grab the unique thread id and delete all entries that contain that thread ID. However when I delete the thread it is not auto-cascading and deleting the related message objects.

The weird thing is that it worked before, but then stopped working, I'm not too sure why.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django version 1.3 there is a on_delete parameter which determinates "ondelete" action, for example:

```
def get_sentinel_user():
    return User.objects.get_or_create(username='deleted')[0]

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))
```

So maybe try:

```
class thread(models.Model):
     message = models.ForeignKey(message, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ...
```

source http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/

Answer (score 1):

That's not how cascading delete works.  Since `thread` has a foreign key to `message`, if you delete a `message`, the cascading effect is to delete all associated `thread`s.  See the documentation for more information and examples:

- [Deleting objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)

You could call `delete` on the associated message if that's what you want.